# Unclear remark that my question is unclear

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions

What's wrong with this community? Only here, I am experiencing such blunt closing.

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/224413/if-spacetime-is-discrete-what-would-space-expansion-mean -- This question has been corrected. Nevertheless, no one seems to bother to reopen it

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/224789/implications-of-observable-universe-growing-indefinitely?noredirect=1#comment484877_224789 -- what is so unclear? How could people answer and comment then?

Both questions have been upvoted.

---

So, what is wrong now? Did the second question become yet more unclear?

---

The questions get upvoted. Why not to reopen? What's the problem?

Comment: Just as a remark, starting a meta discussion with *"What's wrong with this community?"* is a **terribly unconstructive** idea. You should keep in mind that closing your question is nothing against you personally, and keep your emotions in check at all times.

Comment: "keep your emotions in check at all times" kinda relates to the moderators as well, or not?

Comment: I don't think any moderator got emotional about closing your question.

Comment: Maybe. I was simply asking, right?

Answer (score 1):

The first question (currently) has 2 reopen votes, but [3 people said to leave it closed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/110249), so it has been removed from the [reopen queue](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions). It takes 5 people to reopen it (or one mod), so you need 3 more people with the appropriate level of privileges to get it reopened (oftentimes, bringing the post to Meta will result in the "Meta effect" where questions are reopened (deserved or not)).

[I don't think the second question is unclear](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/close/110410), but 5 other people thought so. Though in retrospect, your first part might be considered a duplicate of [**As the universe ages, will we see more stars or less?**](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90024/). It might be the second part that is considered unclear, though I'm not sure I'd agree with that and would hope one of the 5 close voters can comment on that.

Note, though, that there ***isn't*** a requirement that anyone comment on a question about *why* they're voting such a way that they have. It has been my experience that the first close-voter on a question would leave a comment about why they're voting such a way (e.g., "It's not clear to me what you mean by ..." or "We are not a homework help site ..."). I'm not sure why it wasn't done in this case, but, again, it's not a requirement so I *personally* am not concerned about the lack of the comment.

Further, I wouldn't put much stock in using votes as a rationale for your post being okay because (a) there is a small contingent of users on this site that give sympathy votes to (somehow) balance out downvotes and (b) even wildly off-topic questions get upvotes & views simply because (interested) users like the question (I discussed this [previously as well](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7269/why-more-than-a-thousand-views-for-my-closed-question/7276#7276)).

Comment: Meta effect is a peculiar thing! The question you linked got 15 votes after the query was posted on meta & was reopened; I've a feeling that same would happen here also.

Comment: I'm not a particularly big fan of the Meta effect, to be honest. I think crud questions get undeserved votes & reopens for sympathy reasons, rather than for reasons of topicality. It doesn't happen often enough for me to be terribly concerned about it, though.

Comment: So what's the problem still? The questions don't seem to be unuseful for the users. How long will they be closed?

Comment: @ValerySaharov: I cannot tell you what the problem is, as I'm not much of a mind reader & no one has commented why they're not reopening your question. However, your first question has 3 reopen votes while your second has 4 (both need 5 each).